Ошибка повторного объявления
Выскакивает ошибка повторного объявления "invalid redeclaration of type name "newscreen" (declared at line 5)", но проблема в том, что в hpp файле до этого я ничего не объявлял. Возможно дело в неправильном синтаксисе cpp файла, но тогда прошу объяснить или может есть ссылка для материалов уровня последний чайников, где бы это разъяснялось, какой синтаксис применить.
hpp
class newscreen { //5 строчка
public:
void from_hex(unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char, unsigned char);
void to_hex(unsigned char);
//еще 7 подобных "войдов"

class TxArray {
public:
void Create(int *&Arr, const int N);
void Delete(int *Arr);
void Fill(int *Arr, const int N, int valuein);
};

};

void newscreen::TxArray::Create(int *&Arr, const int N) {
Arr= new int[N];
}
//еще две подобных функции для удаления и заполнения

cpp
#include //все инклюды

void newscreen::init(void) {
//func
}
void newscreen::to_hex(unsigned char number){
//func
}

//few more functions

сами функции не расписывал, думаю, мне кажется, что налажал в их объявлении, но не знаю, как должно быть

Забыли #pragma once в самом начале хедера? Если не угадал, составьте [mcve].

Определение функции void newscreen::TxArray::Create(int *&Arr, const int N) в заголовочном файле в будущем может спровоцировать проблему линковки (компоновки), если вы будете подключать этот заголовочный файл в два и более файла исходного кода. Лучше перенести определение в файл исходного кода.
